# Flex Builder on Linux

Tags: linux, flexbuilder

Is there a way to use a Flex Builder on Linux?

Adobe has formally dropped Linux support for Flash Builder IDE.
There is an open source project that exists on Google Code.
So I tried it, but no designer mode and some other compiling problems are there.

I only need to develop my project front end on Linux, because it's back end comes with some Linux based libraries. That's why I can't move into Windows.

If anyone else developing Flex on Linux please give me some help.

Thank you!

Comment: Nobody is developing Flex in Linux?

Comment: FB4.5Linux is working well under Ubuntu10.04.... (No design mode, but no need of design mode if you familiar with flex)

Answer (score 1):

You can develop and compile flex in linux, however, running flexbuilder is problem. Adobe  never released FB UI plugins needed for linux (they also fail with mac os cocoa too). You have two options:

1. Use flexc in terminal with any editor you want. You may also write an ant script or use maven to trigger flexc to compile your project automatically from eclipse. I know several people using it that way and it works.
2. I, once managed to make fb run on linux except for the designer part (for version 3.5). What I did was actually copying all the plugins needed by flexbuilder to your eclipse installation. Since this is not a controlled plugin installation you must be careful about bundle versions and not to override any os specific counterpart. However even if you succeed, there is no way the designer works.

So either way you won't have a design view.